# How to query permission set name who dont have active users assigned.

Tags: apex, soql, query

Requirement:-How to query permission set name who dont have  active users assigned.

I need all the Permission set names that do not have active users assigned.

Comment: Is this possible to create a report with all permissions set with inactive users .Report needs to show only those permissions whose all users are inactive

Answer (score 2):

use this code to get all the permission set names who do not contains an active users

```
for(PermissionSet obj : [SELECT Name, (SELECT AssigneeId 
                                         FROM Assignments 
                                        WHERE Assignee.IsActive= true)
                                         FROM PermissionSet]){
    if(obj.Assignments.size() == 0)
       setPermissionSetNames.add(obj.PermissionSet.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following Query and use with any collection like List/Map to get results:

```
SELECT Id, 
       AssigneeId,
       PermissionSet.Name 
 FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
 WHERE Assignee.isActive = false
```

`Assignee` field reference to **User** object
`PermissionSet` reference to PermissionSet object